# Can I use Orange Authentication France to connect to Live Object?

Tags: orange-api

When I look to APIs doc, it seems that there is a distinct mechanism to authentify user on Live Object : 
[Live Object API](https://liveobjects.orange-business.com/swagger-ui/index.html#/Partners_tokens_management) and [Orange API](https://developer.orange.com/apis/authentication-fr/)

What should I use to develop a Live Object based LORA web application where user identify themself with their LiveObject credentials ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's totally different APIs. Live Objects APIs are not exposed within "Orange Developper".

Moreover the Live Objects "Partners API", you are pointing are reserved for special integrations with partners.

To build an application on top of Live Objects, you just need:
* a Live Objects account (https://liveobjects.orange-business.com/#/request_account)
* use MQTT API: for real time message consumption (bridge mode)
* use REST API: For all other usages (provisioning, data search, device management..)

Both API rely on API key not on oauth2. To create your API Key you have to log into your Live Objects account.

You could find a lot of resources here https://liveobjects.orange-business.com/#/faq that may help you.

You can also get in touch with Orange to expose your needs and get support for your project at liveobjects.contact@orange.com

best regards
F.